# Alamofire error on carthage update

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, carthage

My Cartfile:

```
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" "v4.0.0-alpha.4"
github "ikesyo/Himotoki" ~> 1.3.0
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 3.1.2
github "Swinject/Swinject" == 0.5.0

github "Quick/Quick" == 0.8.0
github "Quick/Nimble" == 3.0.0
```

Error:

```
*** Fetching ReactiveCocoa
*** Fetching Himotoki
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Fetching Swinject
*** Fetching Quick
*** Fetching Nimble
*** Fetching Result
*** Checking out Himotoki at "1.3.2"
*** Checking out ReactiveCocoa at "4faa7bc75cd30682e9e5615bb6359988f0339800"
*** Downloading Swinject at "v0.5"
*** Downloading Nimble at "Nimble v3.0.0"
*** Checking out Alamofire at "3.1.4"
*** Downloading Result at "1.0.1: A New Beginning"
*** Downloading Quick at "v0.8.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/tr/4fjkzly53sv7fwt6yxt1_fl40000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.lsMXnQ.log
*** Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
2015-12-17 13:25:56.420 xcodebuild[21997:5587012] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID F41BD31E-2683-44B8-AE7F-5F09E919790E for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2015-12-17 13:25:56.421 xcodebuild[21997:5587012] Failed to load plugin at: /Users/Matan/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin, skipping.  Reason for failure: *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
2015-12-17 13:25:56.422 xcodebuild[21997:5587012] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID F41BD31E-2683-44B8-AE7F-5F09E919790E for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/RealmBrowser.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Matan/Documents/ObjectiveC/onpi/SwinjectMVVMExample/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/Upload.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Matan/Documents/ObjectiveC/onpi/SwinjectMVVMExample/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Matan/Documents/ObjectiveC/onpi/SwinjectMVVMExample/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/Request.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Matan/Documents/ObjectiveC/onpi/SwinjectMVVMExample/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/ResponseSerialization.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Matan/Documents/ObjectiveC/onpi/SwinjectMVVMExample/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/Error.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Matan/Documents/ObjectiveC/onpi/SwinjectMVVMExample/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/Manager.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Matan/Documents/ObjectiveC/onpi/SwinjectMVVMExample/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/Response.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Matan/Documents/ObjectiveC/onpi/SwinjectMVVMExample/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(9 failures)
```

Comment: What error is displayed if you run `carthage` command with `--verbose` option? Or can you share the log `/var/folders/tr/4fjkzly53sv7fwt6yxt1_fl40000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.lsMXnQ.log`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered an issue with error output similar to yours when running `carthage update` for the latest release of Alamofire. This seems to have been caused by some Xcode plugins not yet fully compatible with the latest Xcode. Temporarily moving those plugins out of the Xcode plugin folder before running `carthage update` worked for me.

In your case, please temporarily move the two Xcode plugins mentioned in the error log, `Unity4XC.xcplugin` and `RealmBrowser.xcplugin` out of `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins` to somewhere else and run `carthage update`.

In my case, CocoaPodUi.xcplugin was the bad boy that caused xcodebuild errors during carthage update.

Another option might be appending the DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs of your Xcode contained in the binary `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist` to `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/<name-of-stale-plugin>.xcplugin/Contents/Info.plist`. You can do this manually using Xcode

```
open -a Xcode ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin/Contents/Info.plist
open -a Xcode ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/RealmBrowser.xcplugin/Contents/Info.plist
```

or automatically on a terminal.

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins -name Info.plist | xargs -IFILE defaults write FILE DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add F41BD31E-2683-44B8-AE7F-5F09E919790E
```

F41BD31E-2683-44B8-AE7F-5F09E919790E is the UUID of Xcode 7.2(7C68) and already provided in the error output above.

```
2015-12-17 13:25:56.420 xcodebuild[21997:5587012] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID F41BD31E-2683-44B8-AE7F-5F09E919790E for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2015-12-17 13:25:56.422 xcodebuild[21997:5587012] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID F41BD31E-2683-44B8-AE7F-5F09E919790E for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/RealmBrowser.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
```

Comment: Thanks @afmm, this was just what I was looking for. :)

Comment: didn't know we could fix that UUID compatibility warning ourselves -- very nice find @mmizutani